# Resistor / Capacitor on digital signal

Tags: capacitor, resistors, signal

I'm new quite new at electronics and trying to learn small tricks too.

In some schematics, I saw they're adding resistors or capacitors on the signal.

1) For example please check U1's 13th leg at the schematic below. *Value of **C5** is 100nF*

**CH340G schematic**

[image: CH340G]

2) In another schematic (*couldn't find it again*) I saw 100r resistors on SPI's MOSI, SCK and CS (chip select) signals. I applied schematic and it's working with and without those resistors.

I can only thing, they're tried to protect the IC.

Note: I do not have an oscilloscope

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different things going on.

1) Series resistors on serial communication systems are generally a part of a larger problem known as "signal integrity analysis" and "electrical termination".

In the case of SPI the most relevant line to need a "termination" is SCK.  Why does a slow line like SCK need termination?  The issue is that while the SCK bus *frequency* is generally MHz the *edge* of that signal may have Gigahertz components from modern transistor technology.  And modern transistors receiving that signal may also be able to respond at Gigahertz rates.

So, you get a launched signal, a transmission line, a reflection or two on the line, and you may get a double-clock event on SCK.  Not good.

Simply adding a resistor in series damps those reflections as well as limits the amount of current that can cause a reflection.  The precise amount of resistance generally isn't too relevant at single digit MHz speeds.

2) If *all* your SPI signals have resistors, are the packages of the communicating chips something like QFN or BGA?  For a package like a QFN, it can be *really* hard to probe specific signals so bringing them to resistors which can be soldered or probed can help.

3) Sometimes the series resistors are there to help out with ESD protection.  I suspect that's what R4/R5 are meant to do in your circuit above.  They could be to help signal integrity, but on such a small board they're probably not relevant for that.

4) The C5/R3 combination is serving as a high-pass filter so that DTR only sees the edge changes on the RESET line--and, in this instance, only rising edges since the resistor, by default, discharges to ground over time.

Comment: Thank you very much. In software development, it's okay to do mistakes but at electronics, it's not :) So that's why I want to figure out and your answer is helpful. Specially 1st answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, that schematic is for a USB-TTL serial converter. The R3 C5 network you pointed out is used to convert a falling DTR signal into a low-going pulse that's sent to the /RESET line on the TTL side. It's commonly used on USB-TTL programmers to reset the device after downloading new code into a microcontroller.

For question 2, yes, small value resistors in series with signals can be used to protect the devices. They might also help the quality of the signals from degrading (something about driving a controlled impedance or something... sorry! it's beyond me).

In general, capacitors are used to stabilize DC values (shunt AC signals to  ground), and resistors are used to control the amount of current that flows through a circuit.  The caps in the schematic around Y1 help the crystal to oscillate in a stable manner.

Comment: Thank you @aMike for your answer.